# Cookie. Не видит

Tags: php, cookie

Ранее не пользовался куками. Решил освоить эту тему.
И столкнулся с тем, что в браузере куки видны, а на странице они не выводятся.
Про то, что объявлять куки нужно до любого вывода я в курсе.

Сложность в конструкции кода.
Сценарий:
 1. На странице html-форма (авторизация). После ввода данных информация отправляется через Ajax в php-файл.
 2. Элемент списка
 3. На стороне сервера идет установка кукисов.
 4. После всех проверок JS перенаправит пользователя на php-страницу с проверкой кукисов.
Вот как раз на этой странице куки не видны.
Может ли это быть потому, что куки ставятся после прохождения Ajax запроса? Не вижу тут никакой связи, но вероятнее всего я просто чего-то не знаю или не понимаю.

Код php обработчика, где ставлю куки:

```
// Присоединяем файл конфигурации
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/aw-config.php');

// Подключаем AW-PHP библиотеку
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.AW_ENGINE_FOLDER.'/'.AW_FUN_FOLDER.'/'.AW_FUNPHP_FILE);

// Принимаем данные из формы
$user_login = $_POST['login'];
$user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
$rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];

// Обнуляем все ошибки
$error_login = '';
$error_pass = '';
$error_connectDB = '';

// Подключаемся к MYSQL
$connectDB = connectDB ( AW_MYSQLDB_PATCH );
if($connectDB){$error_connectDB = '';} else {$error_connectDB = '<p class="error"><strong>Ошибка:</strong> Произошла внутренняя ошибка системы. Обратитесь к Администратору.</p>';}

// Проверяем на валидность введенные данные
if($user_login == '' OR strlen($user_login) <= 0)
{
    $error_login = '<p class="atention"><strong>Внимание!</strong> Не заполнено поле &laquo;Имя пользователя или e-mail&raquo;</p>';
}
if($user_pass == '' OR strlen($user_pass) <= 0)
{
    $error_pass = '<p class="atention"><strong>Внимание!</strong> Не заполнено поле &laquo;Пароль&raquo;</p>';
}

// Конвертируем пароль в MD5 дважды
$user_pass = md5(MD5($user_pass));


// Ищем пару логин и пароль в базе
$sqlAuth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".AW_MYSQL_PREFIX.AW_MYSQL_USERS." WHERE user_login = '".$_POST['login']."' LIMIT 1");
$recAuth = mysql_fetch_array($sqlAuth);
// Сравниваем введенный пароль с тем, что записан в базе
if($recAuth['user_pass'] == $user_pass)
{
    // $noerror = '<p class="ok"><strong>OK!</strong> Логин найден. Пароли совпали.</p>';

    // Генерируем Хэш-код из случайных символов
    $hash = RandomString(20,'lower, numbers');

    // Записываем в БД новый хеш авторизации
    $sql_Auth = mysql_query("UPDATE ".AW_MYSQL_PREFIX.AW_MYSQL_USERMETA." SET meta_value = '$hash' WHERE user_id = '".$recAuth['id']."' AND meta_name = 'hash_code'");

    // Устанавливаем куки
    $userid = $recAuth['id'];
    setcookie("userid", $userid, time()+60*60*24);
    setcookie("userhash", $hash, time()+60*60*24);

    $noerror = "Все прошло успешно! / ";
}
else
{
    $error_pass = '<p class="error"><strong>Ошибка:</strong> Не верный пароль.</p>';
}

// Закрываем базу MYSQL
disConnectDB($connectDB);

// Заполняем массив данных для отправки ответа
$data = array
(
    'error_login' => $error_login,
    'error_pass' => $error_pass,
    'error_connectDB' => $error_connectDB,
    'noerror' => $noerror
);

// Отправляем ответ в формате JSON
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Страница, на которой вывожу куки:

```
echo 'id: '.$_COOKIE['userid'].' / hash: '.$_COOKIE['userhash'];
```

Чтобы убедиться создаются ли куки я в браузере удаляю ранее созданные.
После запуска все работает как часы - куки браузер снова видит, а скрипт нет :(

Попробовал создать отдельную страницу, на ней установил куки и прочел - все работает. Выходит что причина в моем коде, приведенном выше.
Прошу помочь.

Comment: Тоже не шарю в куках и как-то решил бегло почитать о них. Если я правильно понял информацию, это способ хранения каких-то "простых" значений на сервере.. Если это так, то есть более простая альтернатива `localStorage` в JQ.

Comment: Не, куки хранятся на стороне пользователя.

Comment: `localStorage` хранит значения тоже у клиента, это чисто браузерное хранение, а использовать просто - https://tproger.ru/articles/localstorage/

Comment: Спасибо за совет, бегло прочел. Однако я хочу решить свою задачу, ибо не понимаю причины ошибки...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен:
setcookie("userid", $userid, time()+60*60*24, "/");
setcookie("userhash", $hash, time()+60*60*24, "/");
Надо было прописать путь для кукисов.